# How do I get rid of unneeded parameters in a class initiation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

So I'm trying to get the hang of OOP in Python. The problem I have is when initializing my objects for sub-classes, I'm still having to input information which I shouldn't need to.

Specifically, I'm trying to make it so I can create a Person object without specifying can_speak. So I could do something like:

```
John = person("John Anderson")
```

Without having to input `can_speak` as part of the initialization.

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, can_speak):
        self.name = name
        self.can_speak = False

class Dog(Animal):
    pass

class Person(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, can_speak):
        self.name = name
        self.can_speak = True

Bob = Person("Bob the Builder", 3.141)
print(Bob.name)
print(Bob.can_speak)
# Bob the Builder
# True

Sam = Dog("Sam the Mutt", 0.00059)
print(Sam.name)
print(Sam.can_speak)
# Sam the Mutt
# False
```

Here I have to put something as the second input into the initialization, or I get an error. It's a waste like this.

Comment: `def __init__(self, name, can_speak=False):` Default args.

Comment: you _don't_ have to put `can_speak` as a parameter if it's fixed: just do `def __init__(self, name):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do **not have to add a parameter for every attribute** an object has. You can simply fill it in at the `Animal` level, and override it at the `Person` level, like:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):  # look ma, no can_speak parameter
        self.name = name
        self.can_speak = False

class Dog(Animal):
    pass

class Person(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):   # look ma, no can_speak parameter
        super().__init__(name)  # perform a super call
        self.can_speak = True   # override the can_speak
```

You only have to **add a parameter if how such an object should be constructed depends on input**.

Furthermore note that you do **not have to add such an attribute is attached to an object**. You can **attach attributes to classes**, or define methods. For instance:

```
class Animal(object):

    can_speak = False

    def __init__(self, name):  # look ma, no can_speak parameter
        self.name = name

class Dog(Animal):
    pass

class Person(Animal):

    can_speak = True
```

Now we store whether an `Animal` can speak *in* the class. This will result in less memory usage, whereas we can still get whether an animal can speak:

```
>>> a = Animal('foo')
>>> a.can_speak
False
>>> p = Person('bar')
>>> p.can_speak
True
```

We can however still add an attribute `can_speak` to an individual dog (in Belgium for instance, there was a television show about a *fictitious* speaking dog named *Samson*):

```
>>> samson = Dog('Samson')
>>> samson.can_speak = True
>>> samson.can_speak
True
>>> foo = Dog('other dog')
>>> foo.can_speak
False
```

Comment: I would even define `can_speak` as a _class_ attribute.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: that's an additional point I'm currently adding :)

Comment: the question is strange but your answer is nice.

Comment: I thought there would be an elegant solution, but I didn't think it would be this elegant. Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Animal` is the Base class having an attribute `can_speak` Defaulted to the variable passed into the constructor, which is again defaulted to False.

In the child class `Dog` is calling its base constructor so it can't speak. But `Person` is calling the base constructor with a `True` value for `can_speak`.

So you can create an object of person which can't speak as well as an animal which can speak(such as parrot). By following the below method the `can_speak` variable remains constant throughout all the classes and not duplicated in child classes and can be changed by passing an argument instead of changing manually within child class.

Try the following

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, can_speak=False):
        self.name = name
        self.can_speak = can_speak

class Dog(Animal):
    pass

class Person(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, can_speak=True):
        super(Person, self).__init__(name, can_speak)

Bob = Person("Bob the Builder")
print(Bob.name)
print(Bob.can_speak)
# Bob the Builder
# True

Sam = Dog("Sam the Mutt")
print(Sam.name)
print(Sam.can_speak)
# Sam the Mutt
# False
```

Comment: The default value of Animal.can_speak is False. so the dog Can't speak, Incase of person it is overriden to true

Comment: with your method you're then able to create a `Person` which _doesn't_ speak. That exists (even if we're interpreting the question too much...)

Comment: Yeah, but there are cases where a person can't speak and there are cases where an animal can speak(parrot) so this way it is more generic and have scope of over riding attributes even more.

Comment: I like to keep it this way because The default is Always False and you can change it just by passing true without overriding an attribute inside a child class.

Comment: you got a point. but you should [edit] your answer with some explanation and a sum up of on your comments for the answer to be good. Comments are not part of the answer.

Comment: Sure, I will change.

Answer (score 2):

First you should always use the built-in function `super()` and call parent's `__init__()` unless you are really sure you don't want to do that. The parent can initialize more than those two attributes and you would have to copy it into children's `__init__()` which is highly error-prone.

Now you can accomplish your task in several ways:

- Use default value

  ```
  class Person(Animal):
      def __init__(self, name, can_speak = True):
          super().__init__(name, can_speak)
  ```

  In that case you still can create instance of `Person` and set that he can't speak (he can be speechless).
- If you don't want to support speechless people then you can do this:

  ```
  class Person(Animal):
      def __init__(self, name, can_speak = True):
          super().__init__(name, True)
  ```
- But then the parameter can be misleading so you can omit that (from this point the parent and child has different constructor parameters which is usually not a problem):

  ```
  class Person(Animal):
      def __init__(self, name):
          super().__init__(name, True)
  ```